# Derive the equation (repetitively $Q$-switched laser)

Tags: optics, laser

In the book Principles of Lasers by Orazio Svelto in chapter 8.4 there is an equation 8.4.30. I tried to understand how this formula was derived, but I couldn't figure it out. Then it evolved into 8.4.31, which also confused me.

[image: equations]

Comment: Welcome @YeebLun , 
When citing a text, please try avoiding images because they may be displayed poorly on certain devices, and also their content can't be indexed by search engines. Instead use regular text and [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for equations.

Comment: Can you be more specific? In the time between pulses you have to recreate the inversion, so you need a given pumping power. That changes the boundary conditions discussed for getting to inversion from the ground state.